# Поиск файла по расширению и вывод его имени в консоль

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Есть директория. В ней лежит файл. Программа предлагает ввести название директории, а после ввести расширение файла и по этому расширению найти все файлы в данной директории с таким расширением и вывести их полные имена в консоль.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        string path = Console.ReadLine ();
        if (Directory.Exists (path)) {
            Console.Write ("Какое расширение? \n");
            string type = Console.ReadLine ();//ввожу *.docs например, чтобы проверить есть ли файл с таким расширением
            var result =  Directory.GetFiles(path, type);
            if (File.Exists (result)) {
                Console.Write ("Yes! ");
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine ("No! \n");
            }
        } else {
            Console.Write ("No directory! \n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это хорошо, что у вас есть задача. Но в чем вопрос?

Comment: приведите пример вашего кода, тогда мы сможем вам помочь, да и не мешало оформить вопрос правильно, саму задачу вы описали, но как подметил @tym32167 в чем собственно вопрос ? что не получается ?

Comment: @tym32167  Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: @Lolidze Отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Но вы так и не описали проблему. Что у вас не работает? Или ошибка какая?

Comment: @tym32167 программа не компилируется. пишет, что File.IO.Exists не может принимать что-то кроме string

Comment: А, это да. Это потому что `Directory.GetFiles` возвращает коллекцию строк, а не одну строку. Чтобы проверить каждую строку в коллекции вам надо использовать `foreach`

Comment: @tym32167 да, только возвращает он массив, а не коллекцию :)

Comment: @Lolidze под коллекцией я имел ввиду не конкретный тип, но набор элементов, что можно перечислить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы вызываете `GetFiles` или `EnumerateFiles` (в моем случае) вы получаете массив или коллекцию, которую вы должны прогнать через цикл, что бы вывести результат, а вы же зачем-то поставили условие.

Дополнил ваш пример

```
    Console.WriteLine("Путь:");
    string path = Console.ReadLine();
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Какое расширение?");
        string type = Console.ReadLine();

        var result= Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, type) ;
        foreach(var m in result)
            Console.WriteLine(m);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No directory!");
    }
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! ВСе работает:-)

Comment: А не могли бы подробнее рассказать, где я ошибся? там вместо foreach у меня был if и это было ошибкой? или что-то еще?

Comment: @МаксимДонец Если вам ответ подошел, то отметьте его как ответ для данного вопроса. Да, это и было ошибкой, зачем вы вообще писали оператор `if` ? Зачем вам нужна была проверка на существование файла ? `EnumerateFiles` или `GetFiles` возвращают список файлов, вы должны этот список вывести на экран, в данном случае я использовал цикл `foreach`, вы же можете использовать и цикл `for`, как вам будет удобнее

Comment: Посмотрел изначальный вариант кода и сам теперь не понимаю, зачем так сделал. Видимо усталость. Каждый день код пишу, уже каша в голове...Но что поделаешь, учиться нужно:-) Ответ пометил! Спасибо еще раз!